# Como traer datos con ajax a un Modal

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, json

los datos que solicito a la bd por medio de ajax no rellena el formulario modal, he revisado todo pero no le llego al problema, no se si tenga que ver las direcciones de los diferentes archivos, agradecería su ayuda para poder resolver este misterio..

las funciones de php para conectar la base de datos si funcionan ya las probe por separado pero cuando agrego el ajax y el js no se que pasa o no se como conectarme.

Saludos

adjunto el boton del modal

`<button class="btn btn-warning btnEditarUsuario" idUsuario="'.$value["id"].'" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEditarUsuario"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></button>`

este es el código js

```
$(".btnEditarUsuario").click(function(){
    var idUsuario = $(this).attr("idUsuario");
    
    
    var datos = new FormData();
    datos.append("idUsuario", idUsuario);

    $.ajax({

        url:"ajax/usuarios.ajax.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: datos,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(respuesta){
            
            $("#editarNombre").val(respuesta["nombre"]);
            $("#editarUsuario").val(respuesta["usuario"]);
            $("#editarPerfil").html(respuesta["perfil"]);
            

        }

    });

})
```

El archivo AJAX

```
<?php
require_once "../pages/controladores/usuarios.controlador.php";
require_once "../pages/modelos/usuarios.modelo.php";

class AjaxUsuarios{

    /*=============================================
    EDITAR USUARIO
    =============================================*/ 

    public $idUsuario;

    public function ajaxEditarUsuario(){

        $item = "id";
        $valor = $this->idUsuario;

        $respuesta = ControladorUsuarios::ctrMostrarUsuarios($item, $valor);

        echo json_encode($respuesta);

    }
}

/*=============================================
EDITAR USUARIO
=============================================*/
if(isset($_POST["idUsuario"])){

    $editar = new AjaxUsuarios();
    $editar -> idUsuario = $_POST["idUsuario"];
    $editar -> ajaxEditarUsuario();

    }
```

El formulario modal.

```
 <!--=====================================
MODAL EDITAR USUARIO
======================================-->

<div id="modalEditarUsuario" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <div class="modal-content">

      <form role="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <!--=====================================
        CABEZA DEL MODAL
        ======================================-->

        <div class="modal-header" style="background:#3c8dbc; color:white">

          

          <h4 class="modal-title">Editar usuario</h4>

          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>

        </div>

        <!--=====================================
        CUERPO DEL MODAL
        ======================================-->

        <div class="modal-body">

          <div class="box-body">

            <!-- ENTRADA PARA EL NOMBRE -->
            
            <div class="form-group">
              
             <div class="input-group mb-3">
                  <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></span>
                  
                  </div>
                  
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="editarNombre" name="editarNombre" value=""required>
                
                </div>

            </div>

            <!-- ENTRADA PARA EL USUARIO -->

             <div class="form-group">
              
              <div class="input-group mb-3">
                  
                  <div class="input-group-prepend">
                  
                    <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i></span>

                  </div>
                  
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" value="" name="editarUsuario" id="editarUsuario" required>
                </div>

            </div>

            <!-- ENTRADA PARA LA CONTRASEÑA -->

             <div class="form-group">
              
               <div class="input-group mb-3">
                  
                  <div class="input-group-prepend">
                
                    <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-key"></i></span>
                
                </div>
                  
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Agregar Nuevo Password" name="editarPassword" required>
              
              </div>


            </div>

            <!-- ENTRADA PARA SELECCIONAR SU PERFIL -->

            <div class="form-group">
              
              <div class="input-group mb-3">
                  
                  <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    
                    <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-address-card"></i></span>
                  
                  </div>
                  
                     <select class="form-control" name="editarPerfil">
                          
                          <option value="" id="editarPerfil">Seleccionar Perfil</option>
                          
                          <option value="Administrador">Administrador</option>
                          
                          <option value="Especial">Especial</option>
                          
                          <option value="Vendedor">Vendedor</option>
                         
                        </select>
                      

                      </div>

            </div>

            <!-- ENTRADA PARA SUBIR FOTO -->

             <div class="form-group">
              
              <div class="panel">SUBIR FOTO</div>

              <input type="file" class="nuevaFoto" name="editarFoto">

              <p class="help-block">Peso máximo de la foto 2MB</p>

              <img src="dist/img/usuarios/anonymous.png" class="img-thumbnail previsualizar" width="100px">

            </div>

          </div>

        </div>

        <!--=====================================
        PIE DEL MODAL
        ======================================-->

        <div class="modal-footer">

          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Salir</button>

          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Modificar usuario</button>

        </div>

         

      </form>
 
    </div>

  </div>

</div>

<!--/ Modal -->
```

Muy agradecido por su ayuda.. Saludos

Comment: el error que me da en apache logs es **[php:error] [pid 13268:tid 1824] [client ::1:55995] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "ControladorUsuarios" not found in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\posmax\\ajax\\usuarios.ajax.php:18\nStack trace:\n#0 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\posmax\\ajax\\usuarios.ajax.php(32): AjaxUsuarios->ajaxEditarUsuario()\n#1 {main}\n  thrown in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\posmax\\ajax\\usuarios.ajax.php on line 18, referer: http://localhost/posmax/usuarios **  la linea 18 es      `  $respuesta = ControladorUsuarios::ctrMostrarUsuarios($item, $valor);`

Answer (score 0):

Revisa que el controlador esté bien referenciado.
Y en lugar de usar `respuesta["nombre"]` pon `respuesta.nombre` en el success de tu `ajax`.

Comment: seria algo asi `
   $("#editarNombre").val(respuesta.nombre);
   $("#editarUsuario").val(respuesta.usuario);
   $("#editarPerfil").html(respuesta.perfil);` No funciono

Comment: aún no lo solucionas? vi tu comentario y ya vi la posible causa.. revisa que la referencia a tu controlador esté bien, porque dice que no encuentra ese controlador, tal vez no está bien referenciado

Comment: creo que es porque no le llega el valor `$valor = $this->idUsuario;
` del archivo js creo pero no se por que?

Comment: no, aí mismo te dice el error que no encuentra el controlador

Comment: gracias 100 puntos me faltaba una letra en el nombre de la clase ControladorUsarios y es ControladorUsuarios

Comment: @MaximilianoRodriguez si te funcionó mi respuesta, puedes considerar marcar como respuesta correcta a tu pregunta, edite mi respuesta.